# PHP Passing single table row data and date input field using PHP using $_post

Tags: php, forms

I am currently working on an application that was built some time ago, unsure of the framework.

It has a function that when called, generates table rows with the ID for each run. I have added a Date field on the page which I also want to pass along with the tr input id for which the submit is pressed.

```
function run($db)
{
    $select = "";

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `run1`";

    $db->query($sql);

    if ($db->num_rows()) {

        while ($rec = $db->fetch_assoc()) {
            $id = $rec['run1_id'];
            $name = $rec['run1_name'];



            $select .= "<tr>
                            <td><input type='text' id='rowid' name='rowid' value='$id' form='runcountform' hidden>$name</td>
                            <td><input class='btn btn-primary' type='submit' value='Enter Run' form='runcountform'></td>
                        </tr>";
        }
    }
    return $select;
}
```

Currently, I have a form tag that I append the tr to using the form="" attribute, this however only sends the id of the last table row in the table, not the specific row that is clicked.

i.e. If I have 10 rows and the button on row 2 is clicked I get the value from the 10th row not the second.

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <form id="runcountform" method="post" action="__SITE_URL__/run_sheet.php"></form>
        <div class="d-flex mt-4">
            <div class="">
                <h3>Enter Run Sheet</h3>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div class="ml-auto p-2"><a href="__SITE_URL__/production.php" class="btn btn-primary">Cancel</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                __PROMPT__
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row mb-4 mt-2">
            <div class="col-6">
                <select class="form-control" name="day_select" id="day_select" form="runcountform" required>
                    <option value="">Select Day</option>
                    <option value="2">Monday</option>
                    <option value="3">Tuesday</option>
                    <option value="4">Wednesday</option>
                    <option value="5">Thursday</option>
                    <option value="6">Friday</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
            <thead class="thead-light">
                <tr>
                    <th>Run</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                __run__
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

Not very experienced in this, so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you notice, this line

```
<td><input type='text' id='rowid' name='rowid' value='$id' form='runcountform' hidden>$name</td>
```

where `id='rowid`, is assigning the same id to all rows. Try changing it to `id='rowid.$id'` which will assign unique id to each row.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you have one form called "runcountform"
and you add all the inputs with the same name to the form.

When you add inputs with the same name to the form the previous inputs will get overrided so the last input will only be used (as you told that the 10th row value get sent).

One approach is to create a form with different name for each set of input and button so that each form will be sent separately. You may have to move your select inside the form so that the select value get sent.

Another approach is to update input to a different value when you click different buttons, you may need to use javascript to assign a new value according to which button is being clicked.